# 'rownum' vs 'fetch next', What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Tags: oracle

I am working on a large dataset and want to fetch 1000 rows in every iteration. The following queries are my current options:

```
select * 
from Base_table 
where uuid > 325666 
and rownum <=1000

select * 
from Base_table 
where uuid >325666 
fetch next 1000 rows only
```

My questions:  What are the advantages and disadvantages of each query? Which one will be better in terms of performance?

Comment: The oracle blog link exactly explains what you want , https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 That link does not cover the newer `FETCH` syntax.

Comment: @Jon Heller: my bad and thanks. I just wanted to provide the link for OP to explore. Found a small explanation in AskTom site where we also search for the same topic and there are few good explanation available. https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/fetch-first-rows-just-got-faster.